# Right way to implement calling a callback URL in Azure

Tags: azure

If I have an API-only app in Azure App Service where users can send a callback URL in the request. The app sends a POST request to the callback URL upon completion.

There are some complexities in implementing calling a callback URL, for example: retries, time between retries, etc.

**Is there a service, or set of services, in Azure that can help me implement a callback URL?** For example, in AWS the Simple Notification Service (SNS) allows me to send a "push" to a HTTPS endpoint with retries, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what sort of context you might need for your callback, you could drop a message in a service bus queue or topic and then write a simple logic app or function [which is triggered by the presence of a new message in the queue or topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus).

A logic app would provide a solution with no code, only config. A function would require some very basic coding. Logic apps have built in retry features.

[Here is an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-scenario-function-sb-trigger) which somewhat resembles what I think you're after.